# Starting mongod as a service with config file setting

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I want to be able to do `sudo service mongod start` with the option of giving it the path to the configuration file `/etc/mongod.conf`.

So far I have been able to run mongod as daemon by setting the `processManagement.fork` variable in `/etc/mongod.conf` to true as such:

```
# mongod.conf

storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0


processManagement:
  fork: true
```

then running the command:

```
>> mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

However, I think it would be best to run it as a service so I can easily `start` and `stop` it without having to kill the daemon process every time I want to stop the mongod server.

Comment: If you have followed [installation instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) , then you have a upstart file `etc/init/mongod.conf` which does that exactly.

Comment: I have reinstalled using the instructions and when I tried to start mongod, it said it was running but when I printed the service status it was stop/waiting. However, running `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` worked` So I think I have some problem that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Try add your mongo bin directory to path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/mongodb/bin
```

1. Create the service file in /etc/init.d/mongo

> copy the content from [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/debian/init.d) mongodb GitHub repo

2. chmod 700 /etc/init.d/mongo
3. update-rc.d  defaults
4. update-rc.d  enable

Now see you service in

```
service --status-all
```

PS: you should have access to create file in /etc/init.d folder and make nessesary changes as per your system requirement